# Accordian Menu collapsing automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a accordian menu in my asp.net page. The menu is working good but some times it's automatically collapsing. If I reload the page it's some times working but most of the time problem exist. Please find my html and jquery code from jfiddle.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/er6j7ot7/)

```
$('.loc').click(function () {
            $('#sidewrapper ul ul').slideUp();


            if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                $(this).next().slideDown();
            }

        });
```

**Edit:**
my problem is, If I click one list that would be active others should collapse. My code is working fine. But some time(most of the time!) if I click one list that slide is just showing and collapsing automatically without clicking other list.

Comment: i dont see any issue in here,is it browser specific ?

Comment: The problem is exist on both IE11 and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your trying to `slide up` all the unordered list present on your page, if you can just try to `slide up` the list which your currently clicking on, it will work fine.

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.loc').click(function () {
   //$('#sidewrapper ul ul').slideUp();
   $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideUp();

   if (!$(this).next().is(':visible')) {
     $(this).next().slideDown();
   }
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/er6j7ot7/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts.If one list is active then other lists should be collapsed. But in your solution everything become active..

Comment: oh i thought you wanted only current list to be collapsed, so what exactly are you expecting  ?

Comment: then dont you think by default all menu should be collapsed right ?

Comment: my problem is, If I click one list that would be active others should collapse. My code is working fine. But some time if I click one list that slide is just showing and collapsing automatically without clicking other list.